# How to make qml file as plugin？

Tags: qt, qml

qmldir

[image]

qml file

[image]

i creat a default qt quick 2 extension plugin,only added this file.
it can build lock.dll,but i run cmd

---

qmlplugindump Lock 1.0 E:\plugin\lock > E:\plugin\lock\plugin.qmltypes

---

result

[image]

so,is there someone provide a good idea?
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

.pro  files

[image]

pro file : it matched qmldir